# How can I install tesseract on Amazon Linux 2023 , for image to text

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

## uname -a

Linux ip-172-31-21-30.us-east-2.compute.internal 6.1.61-85.141.amzn2023.aarch64 #1 SMP Wed Nov  8 00:38:50 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

it is an elastic beanstalk ec2

I looked in the internet but it cant find the yum packages

Answer (score 0):

According to the Tesseract github and installation page (https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html) the Fedora and other RPM-based distribution binaries can be downloaded here:
https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/home:Alexander_Pozdnyakov:tesseract5
Select tesseract, then "download package", then select CentOS and download the binary .rpm package.
Then you can install the .rpm binary with:

```
sudo yum localinstall <binary>.rpm
```

If you need to automate this you can also just use wget with the precompiled .rpm address.
The website also contains information on adding the repository to yum so you can install it directly.